# how to enable search btn when all 3 inputs have value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, enable-if

I have first, last inputs and country select, I have disabled search btn by default, how do I enable the search btn when all 3 inputs have value in them otherwise, disable the search btn? I have tried to use "and" in js, which is "&&", but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

[jsfiddle][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/x9syr1v1/3/
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x9syr1v1/3/

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/x9syr1v1/4/

Use change function otherwise you'll have tyo foucs out of drop down and use text() for the inputs:

```
$('.first, .last, .country').change(function () {
    if ($('.first').text() == "" && $('.last').text() == "" 
        && $('.country').val() == "") {
        $('.search').attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
        $('.search').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Simple and easy, nice answer. Thanks so much.